# VS2012 Express Web Can't Create MVC4 Apps

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have VS2012 Express Web installed on my machine and can create all different kinds of Projects with exception of MVC3/MVC4 apps. When I click OK on the New Project dialog I get the Select A Template dialog. I notice that the Create a Unit Test Project checkbox is Disabled. Selecting any of the choices (such as Internet Application) gives me this same error: The system cannot find the file specified (Exception from HRESULT 0x80070002).

I have uninstalled and deleted the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\ProjectTemplatesCache and ItemsTemplateChache - and after removal deleted the entire VWDExpress directory so the fresh install would recreate all the templates. I've tried both the web-installer as well as the .iso installer. Has anyone seen this problem or have any idea why I can't create MVC3/MVC4 projects?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I have posted to the MSDN Newgroup and not had any luck there.

regards,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a full installation of Visual Studio 2012.  Uninstalling Visual Studio and everything it came with (SQL Server localDB, Silverlight SDKs etc), restarting, then reinstalling Visual Studio made it work.

Prior to re-installing, I ran ProcessMonitor during an attempt to create an MVC4 app and it kept trying to find an "extension.vsixmanifest" file but couldn't.  I'm not sure which one, since I didn't try reinstalling all my extensions; maybe that will help.